# How can I set a variable in a beforeTextChanged method of an edit text listener, and then call that variable outside of that method?

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener

I'm trying to get a "previous" button- meaning that before the user types into the text box, a variable is assigned to what the edit text already is. Now I'm trying to get it so that after the text changed listener, a button can be pressed to return to the previous words in the text box. But when I do this, I get the message: symbol cannot be resolved. This is because the onclick listener of the button is a separate method. How can I share this variable?

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            final String previousWord = editText.getText().toString();


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }

    });


    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(animScale);


            editText.setText(previousWord);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you're trying to use?

Comment: use editText.addTextChangedListener(this) and btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this)

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the previousWord variable outside of the listeners.

This will allow you to access the variable in both of the listeners.

Something like this:

```
private String previousWord;

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        previousWord = editText.getText().toString();


    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }

});


btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.startAnimation(animScale);


        editText.setText(previousWord);

    }
});
```

Comment: When I add this, I'm getting an underline under private saying: "modifier private  not allowed here", and an underline under previousWord inside beforeTextChanged saying: "variable previous color is acessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final". I update the private to final, and but the the underline in the beforeTextChanged changes to "cannot assign a value to final previous word"

Comment: @MasonM Did you hear "Java" word? or it's a strange word!

Comment: @ABFORCE I'm getting this message: (sorry, I guess I didn't type it correctly in my previous comment) "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'previousWord'"

Comment: @MasonM remove `final` word

Comment: @ABFORCE when I do that the previousWord variable inside the beforeTextChanged method is giving me " Variable 'previousWord' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final"

Comment: @MasonM ooooops! you're right I'll add an answer soon

Comment: @MasonM Done, please try it

Answer (score 0):

First define this class somewhere in your code:

```
class MyWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private String mPrev;
    private EditText mEditText;

    public MyWatcher(EditText editText){
        mEditText = editText;
    }

    public void rollback(){
        mEditText.setText(mPrev);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        mPrev = mEditText.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
final MyWatcher watcher = new MyWatcher(editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.startAnimation(animScale);
        watcher.rollback();
    }
});
```

Another solution could be @jasonwarford's answer, but defining `previousWord` as a **class member** not local variable.

Comment: When I press btnPrevious, the text in the edit text disappears, it doesn't turn back to the previous text

Comment: It disappears when I put the final MyWatcher watcher = new MyWatcher(); and editText.addChangedListener(watcher) into the button's onclicklistener. If I leave it outside the onlicklistener, the text doesn't change at all.

Comment: @MasonM I had a mistake please try the updated answer

Comment: It's still not working properly. When I first press it, it loads the edittext back to nothing, and then after I type into the edit text again and press the previous button it doesn't change.

Comment: @MasonM this should work, do you want to roll back whole word or just a single character?

Comment: I'm trying to get a whole word.

Comment: @MasonM this answer just roll back a single character not whole word

Comment: You have to implements TextWacher, not extends it